# User control content not rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've following code in my WPF app but am not seeing any user control contents when I change the value in the dropdown.Could you advis what  am I missing please?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MainViewModel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel.AccountTypes"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Test.View" x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Test.View.AccountTypes"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Test.View.AccountTypes"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel.AccountTypes"
        Title="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <MainViewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="28" Width="auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <ComboBox Width="360" Margin="1,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccountType, Mode=TwoWay}" TabIndex="0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AC1ViewModel}">
                    <Views:AC1View/>
            </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AC2ViewModel}">
                    <Views:AC2View/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
  public object CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return m_currentViewModel; }
            set
            {
                m_currentViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");    
            }
        }    
            public AccountType SelectedAccountType
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_selectedSearchAccountType;
                }
                set
                {
                    m_selectedSearchAccountType = value;
                      if (SelectedAccountType.Code == "AC1")
                    {
                        m_currentViewModel = new AC1ViewModel();
                    }
                    else if (SelectedAccountType.Code == "AC2")
                    {
                        m_currentViewModel = new AC2ViewModel();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the `CurrentViewModel` property via it's setter? Otherwise `OnPropertyChanged` would not be called.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure what you're doing. It looks like some mistakes were made simplifying your code - m_currentViewModel isn't declared. Is that the same as _CurrentViewModel? Or the CurrentViewModel property? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I can tell from your code is that you never use `CurrentViewModel` property, instead you valorize `m_currentViewModel` private member. So `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel")` is never fired and your view is not getting notified about CurrentViewModel change.

So in your SelectedAccountType property try setting CurrentViewModel instead:

```
public AccountType SelectedAccountType
{
    get
    {
        return m_selectedSearchAccountType;
    }
    set
    {
        m_selectedSearchAccountType = value;
        if (SelectedAccountType.Code == "AC1")
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new AC1ViewModel();
        }
        else if (SelectedAccountType.Code == "AC2")
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new AC2ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a private object `_CurrentViewModel`, something (I don't know what, because you left out that code) called `m_currentViewModel`, and a public property `CurrentViewModel` which you have bound to the ContentPresenter's Content property.

When you change the value of `m_currentViewModel`, nothing happens, because you didn't tell anybody you changed it and nothing's bound to it anyway.

What you need to do is assign the new current viewmodel to `CurrentViewModel`, because then two things will happen:

- The value of `CurrentViewModel` will change, because its setter assigns `value` to `_CurrentViewModel` and its getter returns the value of `_CurrentViewModel`.
- The View will *know* that the value of `CurrentViewModel` has changed, because the setter of `CurrentViewModel` raises `PropertyChanged` correctly. This should cause the content presenter to update its content.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I've now updated the code in my question above.But I'm always seeing contents of AC1 user control even if I chose AC2 in the dropdown value.Please advise.

Comment: It's still broken because you didn't make the changes I suggested: "assign the new current viewmodel to CurrentViewModel". You're still assigning it to something else. @Alex's answer below beat me to hitting submit by 30 seconds, and he provides the actual code changes that I merely described. I'm 99% sure that'll fix the issue; if so, you should accept his answer as correct.